# Рефакторинг роли и файлов переменных для управления учетными записями на группах хостов

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

### Общая ситуация

- Есть отдел из N различных сотрудников + M бездушных машин (типа сервера интеграции).
- Есть множество хостов. Часть используются для тестов, другие на бою, те и те можно группировать по выполняемым задачам.
- Нужно управлять доступом пользователей к хостам, сохраняя конфигурацию в одном месте. Может быть необходимо:

  - Предоставить пользователю доступ к хосту или группе, создавая в системе пользователя и регистрируя ssh-ключ.
  - Отозвать доступ, например удаляя ssh-ключ,
  - Включить или отключить `sudo`,
  - Ограничить `sudo`,
  - Включить или отключить `NOPASSWD`.

### Текущее решение

Сейчас для регистрации пользователей я использую такую схему (пока что пробую всего на двух хостах и двух пользователях):

- Собственный плейбук и роль, в котором используются стандартные модули:

  - [user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html) (создает пользователя, может передать хэш пароля, создаваемый через `passwd --method=SHA-512`)
  - [authorized_key](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) (нужный публичный ключ добавляется в .ssh/authorized_hosts создаваемого пользователя)
  - Плюс собственная задача, которая создает `/etc/sudoers.d/username`:

    ```
      copy:
        content: "{{ item.key }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
        dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/{{ item.key }}"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0400
      with_dict: "{{ users_list }}"
      when: users_list is defined
      become: true
    ```
- Общие файлы inventory (те же, что и для других плейбуков)
- Файлы `group_vars/hostname.yaml`, в которых хранятся публичные ключи и хеши паролей пользователей. Хранятся они в виде словаря:

  ```
  users_list:
    username:
      ssh_key: "ssh-rsa ..."
      password: "$6$..."
      comment: "User Name"
  ```

Такая реализация вынуждает меня для каждого хоста или группы хостов хранить отдельный документ, в котором повторяются данные по пользователям. Это невероятно усложняет поддержку.

### Желаемый результат

Я бы хотел реализовать это примерно в таком виде:

Файл `user_credentials.yaml`, один на всех:

```
user_credentials:
  username:
    ssh_key: "ssh-rsa ..."
    password: "$6$..."
    comment: "User Name"
  username_2:
    ...
```

В каждом `group_vars/hostname.yaml`:

```
users_list:
  username:
    sudoer: yes
    nopasswd: yes
  username_2:
    sudoer: yes
    nopasswd: no
  some_fired_employee:
    state: absent
```

Теперь когда права меняются, нужно просто поменять конфиг в одном месте и выполнить плейбук на нужной группе хостов.

### Проблема

Не понимаю, как писать конкретные таски, чтобы они забирали значения из нужных файлов. Как-то надо сформировать на ходу словарь, в котором будут данные из `user_credentials.yaml`, отфильтрованные по признаку того, что пользователь есть в `users_list`, объединенные с данными из `users_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точности в то решение, которое видится вам идеальным написать может быть и реально, но оно точно будет громоздким из-за вложенности lookup'ов и проверки различных условий.

Зато если немного подкорректировать ваше видение идеального решения, то можно обойтись легким и изящным решением. И уж точно оно будет проще, чем текущее.

Давайте я попробую предложить несколько мелких кубиков, из которых вы без труда подберёте наиболее подходящее для вас решение.

---

Преставьте, что у вас есть папка files\peoples\ в которой лежат папки ivanov и petrov. В папке ivanov два файла: key.pub и pass.txt

В файлах хоста у нас будет записи типа:

```
ans_users:
  - user:
    username: ivanov
    ssh_key_file: "files/people/ivanov/key.pub"
    password_file: "files/people/ivanov/pass.txt"
  - user:
    username: petrov
    ssh_key_file: "files/people/petrov/key.pub"
    password_file: "files/people/petrov/pass.txt"
```

А создавать учётки мы будем простым скриптом:

```
- name: adding users
  user:
    name={{ item.username}}
    password="{{ lookup('file', '"files/people/{{ item.username }}/key.pub"') }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ans_users }}"

- name: add ssh keys
  authorized_key:
    user={{ item.username}}
    key="{{ lookup('file', '{{ item.ssh_key_file }}') }}"
    state=present
  with_items:
    - "{{ ans_users }}"
```

Согласитесь, что мы уже намного улучшили читаемость скрипта за счёт того, что имя файла читаемее, чем sha512_hash.

Давайте попробуем понять, насколько вы готовы пожертвовать сверхцентрализацией. У вас нет никакого централизованного конфиг-файла user_credentials.yaml, который бы описывал всех пользователей. На мой взгляд -- невелика и потеря: этот файл вообще не был нужен изначально и лучшим доказательством этого служит тот факт, что конфиги хостов у меня получились точно такими же, как и в вашем идеальном решении. Эта сверхцентрализация -- излишне жёсткая вещь и тут она бесполезна.

---

Двигаемся рефакторить дальше. Мы упростили создание пользователей и управление их ключами, дальше нужно разобраться с тем, как мы будем управлять sudo.

Предварительно пару слов о best practice. Вместо того, чтобы модулем lineinfile ковырять постоянно файл sudoers рекомендуется управлять группами пользователей. Вам понадобится всего две группы: sudo с паролем и passwordless sudo. Разово настроили и забыли.

Я предлагаю вместо ДВУХ параметров (sudoers, password) пользователям в конфиг-файле просто прописывать ОДИН параметр - группы пользователя. Конфиг становится компактнее, читаемее. Код задания тоже сильно упрощается.

---

Дальше мы рассмотрим вопросы модификации прав, в особенности -- удаление.

- Добавление нового пользователя -- тривиально
- Модификация паролей, ключей, sudo -- тривиально
- Убрать права из одной группы хостов -- держим в files\people два файла с ключом от которого пароль никто не знает и хэш неизвестного никому пароля: достаточно в конфиге увидеть `ssh_key_file: "files/people/null_key.pub"` и сразу будет понятно, что этот пользователь на эту группу хостов уже не зайдёт
- Увольнение сотрудника -- шагом номер раз убираем права со всех групп хостов, доступ убран но в конфигах остался мусор, пусть полежит до дня уборки. В день уборки запускаем отдельный плейбук, который принимает имя пользователя, а затем проходит по всем хостам, удаляя под нож учётку - и как только отработает - чистим конфиги от пользователя и каталог files.

---

В общем-то и всё, пожалуй. Мне кажется, что общее направление понятно и дальше детали сами продумаете. Если же я неправильно угадал ваши вводные -- попробуйте добавить больше деталей в описание задачи, покажу, что ещё можно предложить.

Comment: Спасибо, буду переваривать информацию и пробовать. В целом идея децентрализации понятна и выглядит более гибкой. Вместо уточнения задачи я бы скорее предложил полученный результат на ревью.

Comment: https://github.com/AutomationWithAnsible/ansible-usermanage неплохо выглядит, как по-вашему?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Смотрю на код -- и узнаю фрагменты собственных ролей ;) Очень любопытная штука, спасибо за линк.

Comment: Вот ещё одна популярная: [generic-users](https://github.com/ANXS/generic-users)

Comment: И похоже, что обе не делают passwordless sudo, а вот эта делает, зато очень неудобна. https://github.com/debops/ansible-bootstrap/blob/5ae5fe15f1826ba50cc34a10db9ecc1f82b04c8d/tasks/main.yml#L42

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону ldap + группы + SSO

Comment: Обсуждалось, LDAP нельзя на боевых хостах. Да и вопрос о другом.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?