# Ansible: наследование групповых переменых для sub-групп

Tags: ansible

Здравствуйте

Имеем следущее:
hosts файл:

```
[common]
common-server1
common-server2

[common:children]
servers-group1
servers-group2

[servers-group1]
server1

[servers-group2]
server2
```

в папке/файла `group_vars/servers-group1` перечислены юзеры/группы в переменных `create_groups` с юзерами/группами для этой группы серверов.

```
task:
- hosts: common
...
- name: Create groups
  group: name="{{item.group_name}}" gid="{{item.gid}}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ create_groups }}"
```

Вопрос в следующем: возможно ли в `group_vars/all` или `group_vars/common` задать эту же переменную `create_groups` со списком групп/юзеров, которые должны быть на всех сервераx?

Иначе говоря, некий include файла переменных родительской группы в файл переменных sub-группы

Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Похожую задачу решал, посмотрите, вдруг будет полезно. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476120/181472

Comment: А вообще там есть настройка чтобы неявно делать include на всех переопределениях переменных, но лучше её не включать, т.к. посыплется всё остальное. Можно вынести в переменную `create_groups_common` и явным образом объединять словари в переменных для каждого хоста или группы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не привели пример структуры переменной `create_groups`, но судя по всему это некий словарь следующего вида:

```
create_groups:
  group1:
    group_name: group1
    gid: 123
    ...
  group2:
    group_name: ...
```

В Ansible есть настройка для того, чтобы при переопределении переменной происходило не замещение, а дополнение значения. Но так лучше не делать, т.к. настройка работает на системном уровне, т.е. новое поведение будет вообще везде. Наверняка посыплются какие-нибудь другие роли.

Лучше создать ещё одну переменную, например так:

`group_vars/all.yml`:

```
create_groups_common:
  common_group_1:
    group_name: cgroup1
    gid: 321
  ...
```

При использовании вы можете объединять её с `groups_common`:

```
task:
- hosts: common
...
- name: Create groups
  group: name="{{item.group_name}}" gid="{{item.gid}}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ create_groups_common | combine(create_groups) }}"
```

Почему сначала `create_groups_common`: если в этой переменной вы задали какой-то ключ, в `create_groups` вы сможете переопределить его значение. Если нужно объединять словари рекурсивно (т.е. объединять значения одинаковых ключей), используйте `recursive=True`.

Подробнее: [Combining hashes/dictionaries](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries).